# Eclipse does not launch application after installing on an AVD or real device

Tags: android, eclipse

I have recently started to face this issue that when I Run my application on AVD or Real Android Device via Eclipse it shows that app has been installed but does not launch. When I go and check the phone/AVD it does not show that app in the Apps area but when I go to "Manage Apps" here I can see my app is installed. Is there any reason why its happening?

All the help is much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Ali

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.game.bond.of.jungle"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<application 
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    >

    <activity 
        android:name=".MainActivity" 
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="androidintent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: I'm guessing a manifest issue. make sure you declare your activity correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Probably your main activity is missing the correct intent filters. Make sure it is declared like this:

```
<activity android:name="com.your.package.YourLauncherActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I am already using intent filters and here are the details:

 <activity 
            android:name=".MainActivity" 
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
            
            <intent-filter>
                
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="androidintent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                           
            </intent-filter>
           
        </activity>

Comment: If you are using a library and they are declared there, you'll have to duplicate the information in the main project's manifest. I noticed it doesn't properly merge them and even if the application can be started it doesn't do it when you download from Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you have set the right `Run Configuration`?

1. Right Click your project
2. Choose `Run As`
3. Choose `Run Configuration`
4. Check `Launch Default Activity`
5. Hit `Apply` and `Ok`

Comment: Done. Still the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, but for some reason the **Launch Default Activity** did not work.  I thought I messed something up in the **AndroidManifest.xml** after adding a search intent filter in the project, but that was not the problem.  It would not let me debug either, although the app would start fine when launched from the device.

This worked for me:

1. Right-click on the project
2. Select **Run As**
3. Select **Run Configurations...**
4. Select your application from the list on the left
5. Manually select **Launch: MainActivity** (or whatever you have it named) as the Launch Action instead of the default
6. Select **apply**

Answer (score 0):

Number one thing to check in a situation like this is, look around the AndroidManifest.xml file. Most of the time,

- if you had imported a project from SVN, Git or from existing source code your AndroidManifest.xml file might have replaced with a new one which doesn't specify which Activit(y)ies.java files are there and which one to bring up as the Launcher activity.